# how to remove element from session storage array when there are lot of

Tags: javascript, arrays, session-storage

I am trying to remove elements from localStorage array. all i could find is `localStorage.removeItem(key);`

I couldn't understand how it works because I have 2 sessionStorage. is that okay?

I have this so far

```
var theCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ProductName")); // Retrieving
var quantity = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("QuantityOFprod"));
var prodprice = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("sum"));
```

ProductName, QuantityOFprod and sum is arrays.
I don't now how to form the localstorage.removeItem to select the array and then select an element inside the array. I have tried this

`sessionStorage.removeItem("ProductName", JSON.stringify(namee));`

namee is the a variable which contains the element I want to delete inside the specific sessionStorage array. But all it was doing is deleting everything.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this way:

1. read the entry
2. decode from JSON
3. remove the element
4. encode to JSON
5. update the entry

   ```
   tmp = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ProductName"));
   delete tmp["key to remove"];
   sessionStorage.setItem("ProductName", JSON.stringify(tmp));
   ```

Done.